# Filter must not be larger than input - tensorflow+Keras potential issue

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm using keras with tensorflow and trying to build a VGG-like model. at certain stage I have a tensor of size (h,w,c)=(2,2,512) and I'm calling :

```
model.add(Convolution2D(nOutputPlane,3,3,border_mode='same'))
```

And get the following error:

```
ValueError: Filter must not be larger than the input: Filter: (3, 3) Input: (2, 2)
```

As far as I understand, it should be OK as long as border_mode is 'same', isnt it ?

So any idea why I get this error ?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using `Keras 2.0` try `padding='same'`.

Comment: Thanks, Marcin :) . I tried it and indeed it works. :) I also tried it with theano backend and also it worked. the limitation probably originated in tensorflow (version 0.10).

Comment: So may I form the answer?

Answer (score -1):

No. The `border_mode` (also called padding type) is applied to the **output** of the convolution.

Thus if your convolution's input is 2x2 you must have a 2x2 (or 1x1) filter to produce a 1x1 (or 2x2) output. Then if `border_mode='same'` the output is padded with the right amount of zeros in order to have the same size of the input.

If you want to apply a 3x3 convolution on a 2x2 input you have to pad it **before** of the convolution operation.

P.S: padding a 2x2 input making it a 3x3 is an asymmetric padding that's unusual. Check your network structure, usually everything is somehow symmetrical

Comment: Thanks for the response, nessuno. not sure why padding has to be done before. I thought its part of the API and internally this is what the library do. also, I agree with your comment on the assymetric padding, but when I pad with border_mode='same' where the filter is 3x3, I would expect it to pad symmetrically adding 1 from each side (i.e. 2x2 grows to 4x4). so I assume its still OK. its symmetric. Anyway, I tried it with theano backend and with tensorflow 1.0 and both did work OK.